# Null pointer exception in webdrivermanager

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
package base;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Page{
    
    public static WebDriver driver;
     
    public Page() {
        if(driver==null) {
          WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
          driver.get("https://www.zoho.com/");
          driver.manage().window().maximize();
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `driver` is still `null` by the time you are calling `driver.get()`. You need to initialize it to an actual `WebDriver` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `driver` inside `if(driver == null){..}` will ofcourse be null and when you are trying to do `driver.get("https://www.zoho.com/");` you are getting NPE.

You have forgot to assign to the `driver` variable.

```
       if(driver==null) {
          WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
          driver = new ChromeDriver();
          driver.get("https://www.zoho.com/");
          driver.manage().window().maximize();
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
```

Comment: Actually now i have given if(driver==null),even before giving that,i got the NPE @ driver.get("https://www.zoho.com/");

Comment: So are your still getting NPE with this code? If so, then webdrivermanager is not finding the installed chrome installed in your system.

Comment: I have assigned the ChromeDriver to the driver variable,right?is it not assigned?

Comment: No, This line `WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup()` doesnt assign the driver variable. Please check my code.

Comment: @vaishnaviA.N. any updates ? Did it work for you?

Comment: yeah perfect !   Thank you very much @Abhinaba Chakraborty, I was thinking what was going wrong with my code,Thank you again...